# Can we conclude that $\int_a^b u(x)v'(x)dx=-\int_a^b v(x)u'(x)dx$ if $v$ has compact support in $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Actually, I'm doing a more general case. But let me start from a basic question and see if I can apply the recipe to a general one.

Let us say that $u$ and $v$ are smooth functions defined on the whole real line with $v$ supported compactly on some closed interval $[a,b]$. If we do partial integration on this interval, then elementary calculus tells us that
$$\int_a^b u(x)v'(x)dx=[uv]_a^b-\int_a^b v(x)u'(x)dx.$$
Now I was wondering if the so-called boundary term $[uv]_a^b$ can be abandoned with the help of $v$. As
$$\mathrm{supp}(v)=\overline{\{x\in\mathbb{R}:v(x)\neq 0\}}$$
is a compact subset of $[a,b]$, I can imagine that those points at which $v$ is nonzero are condensed into a subset of $[a,b]$ that touches neither $x=a$ nor $x=b$. This, if it is true, will allow us to dispose of the boundary term. However, I do not know how to describe the preceding statement mathematically and rigorously. Can somebody help me out? Thank you.

Comment: $\operatorname{supp}(v) \subset [a, b]$ implies that $v(a) = v(b) = 0$, so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fact that $\mbox{supp}\;v\subset [a,b]$ and that $\mbox{supp}\;v$ is closed in $[a,b]$ follows that $v$ has to be $0$ at $a$ and $b$. Suppose that $v$ is not $0$ at $a$ or $b$, then by the continuity of $v$ is there an open neighborhood around $a$ or $b$ at which $v$ is nonzero and that would mean that the support of $v$ is larger than $[a,b]$. Thus $v$ is $0$ at $a$ and $b$ for sure.

Comment: Judging from your argument, I think we can ditch the hypothesis that $v$ has **compact** support without altering the result. It seems that only $v\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is needed and, of course, the support needs to sit in the interval.

Comment: Yes i think that's true!